# Grabbing filename from image URL

Tags: javascript, regex, imgur

I'm making a pretty basic Chrome extension that I use primarily for personal use and use between friends. In any case, I essentially have a URL that looks like this:

`i.imgur.com/abcd123.png` or
`imgur.com/a2b3c78` or even
`i.imgur.com/herp321.png?1`

The only thing I need out of these URLs are the 7 character codes prior to the extension. In these examples, `abcd123`, `a2b3c78`, and `herp321`.

I've been running a `.replace` that won't catch exceptions like the third example, and even attempting to throw some regex at it (Which I haven't been able to get even close to functioning properly). The only part of the URL that is constant is as follows, with the code marked as `x`:

`imgur.com/xxxxxxxx`

The URL may have a varying beginning, and a varying end immediately after the 7-digit code, but the above is constant. Is there a way of pulling only this alphanumeric filename from the above example, regardless of what prefaces the URL or any modifiers/extensions added to the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
matched=str.match(/imgur.com\/(.{7})/);
//matched[1] will have your result
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple aproach:

```
 var text   = 'i.imgur.com/herp321.png?1'
 var regex  = /imgur\.com\/(\w{7})/;

 console.log(text.match(regex)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/.+\/([a-z0-9]+).+/
```

in JS:

```
var imgUrl = 'i.imgur.com/dsf8635235.png?sdgdsgdsg'
  , matches = imgUrl.match( /.+\/([a-z0-9]+).+/ );

console.log( matches[ 1 ] ); // dsf8635235
```

Some variations:

```
console.log( 'imgur.com/dsf8635235'.match( /.+\/([a-z0-9]+).+/ )[ 1 ] ); // dsf8635235
console.log( 'i.imgur.com/dsf8635235'.match( /.+\/([a-z0-9]+).+/ )[ 1 ] ); // dsf8635235
console.log( 'imgur.com/dsf8635235?1'.match( /.+\/([a-z0-9]+).+/ )[ 1 ] ); // dsf8635235
```

etc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It's spitting out values like this:

`["http://i.imgur.com/M5rtaNS.jpg", "i", index: 0, input: "http://i.imgur.com/M5rtaNS.jpg"] `

Comment: Correct. `match` function returns `Array` and as you can see in `console.log` I get `1` index of that array that contains of string what you need

Comment: I printed out the entire `matches` variable. At index one, you can see the value is `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match function with an regex expression for that.

EDIT:

This should work:

```
var urls = ["i.imgur.com/abcd123.png", "imgur.com/a2b3c78", "i.imgur.com/herp321.png?1"];
var reg =  /\/(.{7})/;

for(i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {
  reg.exec(urls[i]);
  console.log(RegExp.$1);
}
```

Comment: No luck, spits out these values: `"//i.imgu", index: 5, input: "http://i.imgur.com/qvjrnFL.jpg"] `